# Given two circles, arc length of the intersection

Tags: geometry

If I have the radius of each circle, and the distance between them, how can I calculate the arc length of each arc in their intersection?

Comment: Hint: you can compute the length of the overlap as $(r+r') - d$, where $r,r'$ are the radii and $d$ is the distance between the circle centers.

Comment: @lightxbulb: How does that help?

Comment: Draw an image and see for yourself. The arc length of the intersection is a function of it @TonyK.

Comment: Not to mention that what he's asking is available with a rudimentary google search, with derivations and everything.

Comment: @lightxbulb: But what to search for? It's like when we asked the teacher how to spell a word, and she said "Look it up in the dictionary!" Perhaps [this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) might help the OP (although it doesn't use your $(r+r')-d$ expression at all).

Comment: @TonyK look closer it does involve it. Everything he had to search for is circles intersection.

Comment: Solve for the angles the triangle formed by the segment between the centers and the two radii to an intersection point.

Comment: I had seen that page, but my attempts to implement it were unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T$ be one of the intersection points of the circles. By Heron's formula the area of the triangle $O_1TO_2$ is
$$A_{O_1TO_2}=\sqrt{P(P-R_1)(P-R_2)(P-D)},
$$
where $P=\frac{R_1+D+R_2}{2}$ is the semi-perimeter of the triangle.

On the other hand the same area can be written as
$$A_{O_1TO_2}=\frac{1}{2}R_iD\sin\phi_i,
$$
where $\phi_i$ is the angle at $O_i$.

Finally we have:
$$
\Phi_i=2R_i\arcsin\frac{2 \sqrt{P(P-R_1)(P-R_2)(P-D)}}{DR_i};\quad i=1,2,
$$
where $\Phi_i$ is the arc length in question.